# PHP global variable visible by different clients

Tags: php, variables

Long time with C - new to PHP.

Please excuse me if I use the word/term in my question.

I have a function that is called multiple times within a page execution.  The function's result depends on the previous sub-result held in variables.  I have written the function using a global variables for those "sub-results" so they are saved and used again in the next function call.

My concern is when multiple clients hit the server requesting the same page that those "sub-result" variables would be corrupted by multiple pages being executed at the same time.

Is this a concern?

If so, can I have the "sub-result" variables local to a function that is called within page execution and pass them into the function by reference?  This should keep the variable's scope limited to the current client's page execution and not affected by other clients, right?

If that is correct -- is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Each client (better say request) has its own PHP context execution, meaning you can use global variables and you don't need to worry for that.

Comment: tilz0R is completely right. Each connection in php runs on it's own process with it's own memory allotment. If you want shared variables, you'd have to write them to a database or a file.

Answer (score 3):

Each PHP client (better say request) uses its own data context. This means that if `2` clients are connected at the same time and execute the same PHP code, their variables are not shared and cannot influence to each other.

As pointed by Dan Lugg in comments:

> You’d need to use an external data persistence technology to “share” values across PHP processes. Any conventional database/store/file (accounting for locking) would enable you to share state. But, as mentioned, no variables (regardless of static/global modifiers) are shared between processes

Comment: Thanks - That makes sense to me, but reading all the PHP documentation I could find suggested that it was shared.

Comment: @JHinkle Because it is not.

Comment: @JHinkle You’d need to use an external data persistence technology to “share” values across PHP processes. Any conventional database/store/file (accounting for locking) would enable you to share state. But, as mentioned, no variables (regardless of static/global modifiers) are shared between processes.